# Accept documents from client

Tags: docusignapi

I had question about JWT few days and everything works perfect.
Now another question and not sure if that is possible.

I beside sending envelope, I want user to upload some documents in JPG or PDF format, when they are done signing.

Is there anyway in to do that or docusign is only for signing documents?

Answer (score 1):

Upload documents where? If you want the signer to upload documents to DocuSign, that can be done by adding the `Attachment` tab type to your signing request (envelope).

[Attachment tab documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/attachments/).